# Python-3.4.0 - arrow keys display special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, arrow-keys

I've just installed a new Python-3.4.0 on Debian 7.4. Every thing seems OK except when I use the arrow keys up / down to recall previous commands, the interpreter displays control characters.

[image: arrow-keys]

I remember that this feature was a specific program plugins .. isn't it ?

It's not blocking but boring ..

Comment: And **how** did you install Python 3.4 on your system? Did you compile it from source?

Comment: And those are not all that special characters; they are [ANSI control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which are not being interpreted as there is no readline library active.

Answer (score 3):

You have a Python installation without `readline` support. Install [`libreadline-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libreadline-dev) and re-run `configure`, then recompile and reinstall.

You could be missing other dependencies however, you'll want to consult the [Python 3.2 dependencies](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python3.2) and install corresponding dev packages for those; at a guess you'd want:

```
libbz2-dev
libssl-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libncursesw5-dev
libffi-dev
libdb-dev
libexpat-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Martijn, I'm going to follow your advice and recompile Python. Not That I'm using a Python-3.4.0 version

Comment: @EmmanuelBrunet: Stack Overflow is not a software support site, and these are not 'ticket's :-) We are trying instead to build a body of questions and answers that are useful to a *wider* audience. Not just you and me, but future visitors with similar problems as well.

Comment: That correct Martijn, when I refer to tickets it's just as a record of course available for everyone. It's just to flag the problem as Solved . How to accept the answer as mentioned by Darkhogg ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBrunet: I linked you to the Meta article on how to do that below your question; here it is again: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) This is voluntary but *much appreciated*. :-)

Comment: @EmmanuelBrunet: but basically there are big green `V` marks on each answer (underneath each set of voting buttons), that let accept *one* of the answers on your question. Do so only if you feel the answer has been helpful to you.